# how to create an html form for a model in playframework

Tags: html, forms, playframework

In my application ,I have to present the user with an `address input form`.I have an `Address` model as given below.Do I need to create an html page from scratch to capture the user input,Or can I generate a form similar to the `crud page in admin` area?Which is the correct way to do this in `playframework`?

```
public class Address extends Model {    
    @Required
    String addressLine1;

    String addressLine2;

    String city;

    String state;

    String pincode;

    String phoneNumber;

    String country;
...
}
```

Comment: I'm also still struggling to find the best pattern to auto generate  forms withough going through the whole crud controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CRUD module to capture user input is easier and quicker way. CRUD Module exists for such cases. Regarding whether this is the correct way, it depends. It you have lot of customization then you can overide the crud templates and it should work.

Just create a Addresses Controller extending CRUD. It would be available as part of /admin/. Thats it.

Comment: thanks.if I want to use a drop down list instead of txtfield for country,should I copy/paste the <select...> html snippet inside the crud template?

Answer (score 3):

You can reuse the CRUD tags without the CRUD controllers!

```
#{crud.form class:'models.ModelName' /} 
#{curd.form object:anyInstance /}
```

Please see my answer [Advanced customization of CRUD forms and controllers in Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685384/#8696808) for more details.

PS.

This question was already asked but the accepted question was not satisfying for me, and I wanted to make it into a more generic question. So I asked it again but, still not getting any answer!, I finally found the solution myself :)