# playframework reuse Model in crud.form and non crud forms

Tags: crud, playframework-2.0

I have a Model that i use for some forms and I generated a CRUD
for this Model.

In CRUD I want to hide some fields so I use the CRUD.Exclude annotation from CRUD module 
to hide them.

In other non-CRUD forms I want to reuse the CRUD.form tag but I also want 
to show the excluded fields.

- Is there a flexible way to do this?
- Should I add the CRUD.form fields in the non-CRUD form by hand?
- Is there a way to generate them dynamically both for CRUD and some non-CRUD forms?

I believe I should write another form tag but I'm not sure on how can I pass
the fields of the Model to it.

Any idea on how to design this feature?

Comment: Just to be sure: are you really using playframework 2? Does the content of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685384/advanced-customization-of-crud-forms-and-controllers-in-play/8696808#8696808 answer your question?

Comment: yes i'm using playframework2. i saw your post and it is interesting..i ended up reusing the crud.form fields tag to show the fields i want.

Comment: yeap that is in my opinion the best solution - though I'm still on play! 1.* series...

Comment: when i use crud for non-crud forms i experience a strange error explained in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220495/playframework-random-crud-error#comment11633246_9220495 . do you have an iidea how to solve this error? am i not using the crud correctly in non crud form? i have to construct type and object and pass it to render for form like in controller action in question link. can you help on this? -thanks