# playframework random CRUD error 

Tags: java, crud, playframework-2.0

when i execute the below controller action I get the error attached at end of this question.
when getting this error and if i refresh the page in browser the controller view page displays with no error.
i'm not sure what causes this error at first request of beleow controller action?

```
/**
     * controller to register new user.
     *  Shows registration screen.
     */
    public static void registration() throws Exception {

        ObjectType type = ObjectType.forClass("models.User");

        Constructor<?> constructor = type.entityClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);

        Model object = (Model) constructor.newInstance();
        /*System.out.print("type=");
        System.out.println(type);
        System.out.print("object=");
        System.out.println(object);*/
        render(type, object);
    }
```

----Exception error trace--------------

```
23:12:14,229 ERROR ~ 

@69bf92hlc
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /registration

Template execution error (In {module:crud}/app/views/tags/crud/types.tag around line 3)
Execution error occured in template {module:crud}/app/views/tags/crud/types.tag. Exception raised was NullPointerException : null.

play.exceptions.TemplateExecutionException
    at play.templates.BaseTemplate.throwException(BaseTemplate.java:86)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:257)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate$ExecutableTemplate.invokeTag(GroovyTemplate.java:379)
    at {module:crud}/conf/routes.(line:4)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:232)
    at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:187)
    at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:162)
    at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:190)
    at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:164)
    at play.mvc.Router.load(Router.java:48)
    at play.mvc.Router.detectChanges(Router.java:219)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:478)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:282)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:424)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAssignableClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:453)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader$getAssignableClasses.call(Unknown Source)
    at {module:crud}/app/views/tags/crud/types.tag.(line:3)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:232)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: can you please post your entire controllers for the CRUD module you created?

Comment: @BigFatBaby: i use the default play generated CRUD.java controller. it is the one play generates once we enable the crud module. here is this CRUD.java controller class : https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/modules/crud/app/controllers/CRUD.java

Comment: well i must confess i was completely unaware you could go about the CRUD module like that... i just set up the CRUD from their tutorial, and the approach was clean, fast and simple... you can check it out here http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide7

Comment: that's what i'm doing. i use crud in a non crud controller class.

Comment: this error happens randomly. someties it doesn't occur. it appears randomly . maybe Play encounters problem loading the User class for some reason. it seems it has to do with Class.forName("models.User") not being loaded correctly sometimes. is it a bug in Play? any Idea how to eliminate this error?

Comment: the CRUD is built to be autonomic... at least that's my understanding of it... you create controllers that extend CRUD in order to define the objects that will be handled in the CRUD - i never saw someone using the CRUD in other classes... why do you need it to be that way?

Comment: I have a User registration form that i use the crud module to handle it's logic. i thought it would be nice to use crud for both my admin area and also for my registration form. do you think using the crud in the registration form is not a good Idea? i just wanted to take advantage of the good crud functionality and use it for validation in my registration form which is a non crud form. what you think?

Comment: i recommend using the CRUD for administrative purpose only, the form can be validated via the validation interfaces Play! provides... check out their tutorials on how to create a proper form - it's fairly simple and very robust (yes i would marry this framework given the opportunity)

Comment: It sounds indeed a bit over-complicated what you are doing: inside Registration you already know which model you want, so go on an initialize as it should be - as a User. You should also implement a blank/edit/view pattern. Validation is as easy as using `Validation.hasErrors`

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for you error is that when you first try display the form there's no object created yet, so the `Exception raised was NullPointerException : null.`

Unluckily I'm not familiar with Play 2.* and do not plan on starting before it's more stable, but I think I understood that CRUD generation [is not included nor fully supported](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/msg/6472292b92859edc) there, so you are probably using code from play1 crud?

I think the solution in your case is to better cover the New(blank) / View / Save pattern; seeing your Routes might also help to understand this precise issue.

In any case, considering you are not generating an unknown model type, rather always a `User` one, what is the real advantage of going through this complicated pattern?

You should do something like

### blank

```
User user = null
render()
```

### view/edit

```
User user = User.findById(id);
```

### save

```
public static void save(@Valid User object) {

    if(validation.hasErrors()) {
        params.flash(); // add http parameters to the flash scope
        User user = object;
        render("User/show.html", user);
    }
}
```

Comment: it seem i overcomed this error! the trick is i extend my controller with CRUD and add annotation  `@For(models.User.class)` to my controller class. this seems to solve the issue. i still need to do more test to see if this error is definitely eliminated by the  two changes i introduced.

Comment: one nuisance after i did the annotation `@For(models.User.class)` is my controller class `SignUp` is listed in the admin crud table. how can i tell crud not to list `SignUp` ? or at least change the name `SignUp` to `Users`?

Comment: @othman Yes `@For` does make it appear in the admin section; mmh, I'll take a look what happens behind the curtains that make it work, and maybe I'll find how to _not_ show it in the admin itself. Stay tuned :D - or if you find the solution yourself, let us know ;-) !

Comment: yes we can hide our controller in the CRUD ndex.html view. in this template i hacked the  tag as follows: 
`#{crud.types}                                                      %{ System.out.println(type.name)}%
#{if type.name != "SignUp"}                                          ...the rest of the code unchanged`                                       as you see i tell the CRUD index.html to skip my clss and not show it in the CRUD table.

Comment: I was thinking at something less 'hacky' but if you are happy with it, go for it! In any case I do not think there's an easier way. `public static Class<? extends Model> getEntityClassForController(Class<? extends Controller> controllerClass) {` checks for @For annotations and directly returns them, there's no parameter or option.

Comment: yes i agree it is quit a hacky solution. I hope there is any better and cleaner way to do it? maybe Play must provide a way to customize the crud controller classes (filter the ones you want to hide ).

Comment: the drawback of this "hacky " method is whenever i run `$play deps` the CRUD views/index.html is reset to original version and i have to add the code change again. is there any better method to hide a controller class from the CRUD list in CRUD/views/index.html?

Comment: BTW I still get this Random error ! (described in question post). eventhough i did the changes above it still popups sometimes randomly. i don't know what it the cause of it? is it again that i disabled the 'SignUp' controller class from CRUD index list. i'm not able to understand the real cuase of this error!

Comment: @othman Unluckily I do not have much experience with playframework2, and my undestanding is that the CRUD module is [not really supported with Play2](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/msg/6472292b92859edc). I really suggest you go with a solution on the lines of my answer (not strictly, just the idea) which will surely turn out more robust and quicker to get running!

Comment: yes thank you. i'll probably not use CRUD for the registration process. that's maybe better.thanks