# How to make some field disable in CRUD edit page?

Tags: playframework, crud

I have a field which I do not want to user to edit that. So I want to disable that in CRUD edit page. How can I achieve that ? 
Thanks.

Comment: please explain your question...

Comment: edit it to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override the crud blank.html with **play crud:ov MyEntities\blank.html**
Then edit the file and add the fields you are interested in in you your form tag:

```
#{crud.form fields:['username', 'firstname', 'lastname' ]/}
```

You can also use the custom tag to [customise](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/guide7) any fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can mark the field you don't want to appear in the CRUD with the `@Hidden` annotation.

This just stops the CRUD from displaying it, or allowing it to be edited.

```
import controllers.CRUD.Hidden;


class MyEntity 
{
    ....

    @Hidden
    public int myInvisibleField = MY_DEFAULT_VALUE;
```

It does mean that your putting UI details in your Model, which you might not want.

Answer (score 0):

As a more general answer, there is a lot you can do by overriding the crud templates.

Very little modifications can change your life!

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696808/422670

I now basically leave with my own, completely overridden CRUD templates.

I can change the name of the object for the input, make some fields read only, add jquery datapicker required classes directly...

There's little you can't do with and you do not need to use the server side of it.

This allows you very easily to use the crud templates in your code without using the admin application.

PS.
rather then using the official play `crud:` command, i simply copied over all crud tags into my own project folder :)