# Using CRUD and the Java Play! framework to populate multiple models over a multi-part form

Tags: java, playframework, crud, playframework-1.x

I have a Java Play! application built in Play! 1.2.3 with several models that interlink.  In particular, there is a list of formatted text objects generated by one model that are returned as part of another model, like this:

```
@Entity
public class Parent extends Model {

    @Required
    @Expose
    public String name; // and a dozen others

    @Expose
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    public List<Child> fields;  

}
```

However, rather than create each `Child` object in its own form, I want to have sections of the main form devoted to creating a fixed number of these objects.  So there would be a "name" field on the form, but also (for the sake of argument) two sets of fields, each corresponding to a `Child` object, below that on the form.

Incidentally, the reason for using a `List` in this case is that, in future, we might want to make `Parent` objects with different numbers of fields, in which case we would design new forms.

Is that possible?  The alternative seems to be very cumbersome!

Additionally, because this object is going to be quite long, I would ideally like to populate it over a multi-page form, but it isn't obvious how I could do that short of making all the pages part of one dynamic page or posting temporary variables from page to page, both of which have no persistence and seem to make all the magical usefulness of CRUD sort of pointless.  Is there a recommended method for splitting a controller form over several pages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685384/advanced-customization-of-crud-forms-and-controllers-in-play#8696808

Looks relevant!